# Can't get Tensorflow 2.9 on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a custom environment for a TF agent but for any modules that I need I get the error:
`ImportError: This version of TensorFlow Probability requires TensorFlow version >= 2.9; Detected an installation of version 2.6.3. Please upgrade TensorFlow to proceed.`

For `!pip install tensorflow --upgrade`I get:
`Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.6.5)`

I also tried `!pip install tensorflow-macos` because it was suggested on pypi.org but then I get:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-macos (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-macos`

If I try to specify 2.9 with `!pip install 'tensorflow==2.9' --upgrade` that does not work either:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.9 (from versions: 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3) 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.9
```

I also tried all of these in my Mac terminal (with `python -m pip...`) as well as in VS code terminal but I really can't seem to get the Tensorflow version that I need for the agents and environments …

Answer (score 0):

Ok so apparently, Tensorflow 2.9 is only available on macOSX 10.14 and onward ... yikes

Comment: 10.14 is only 4 years old, imagine that!